# Which is my "instance name" in Google MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

**jdbc:google:mysql://[your-project-id]:[your-instance-name]/[your-database-name]**

↑
This is the URL that Google Documents suggest for connecting to your database (taken from here https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-createapp).

I know my *project ID*, and I know it is correct. Same with the *database name*. **But I'm not sure which is the *[your-instance-name]* parameter.**

```
String url = "jdbc:google:mysql://elliptical-trend-259112:default/testdb";
conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "*****");
```

This is what I've tried until now.

Where can I get the instance name?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to: [The cloud SQL instances page](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances?project=_&_ga=2.244852866.-684034871.1503087936) you should be able to find it there.

Comment: Indeed! It was there on the fourth column at "Instance connection name" label. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have been of help.